# RxJava,Retrofit Error :Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, rx-java, retrofit2, gson

I am using Retrofit and **RxJava** Library and trying to parse this url:

My code is as below.

**APIInterface.java**

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("/bins/tdze5")
    Observable<List<Student>> getdata();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private List<Student> list;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    getData();
  }

  private void getData() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Observable<List<Student>> observable = apiService.getdata().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    observable.subscribe(new Observer<List<Student>>() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d("error",e.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(List<Student> students) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.d("response size", String.valueOf(students.size()));
        for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
          Student student = new Student();
          student.setId(students.get(i).getId());
          student.setName(students.get(i).getName());
          list.add(student);
        }

        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

My Model Class is as below

**Student.java**

```
public class Student {

private String id;

private String name;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
} }
```

I am getting

> D/error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was
>   BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ in Log

I have searched everywhere about this error but I couldn't find anything about RxJava and Retrofit.

Comment: Its nothing but your response is an object but you are trying to fetch as array can u post your json response

Comment: It expects an array, you give it an object. The main problem with your model class. you are not parsing it correctly. Can you post your response over here,what are you  getting in response from server?

Comment: thanks for the help

Comment: @shahid17june i got blank response from server and onError() get called.

Comment: my model class is simple with String id,name and getters and setters methods of tham

Comment: can you please share the response.

Comment: For libraries, are you also using Gson?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this one more `class` and use it like below.

```
public class ResponseClass {

    @SerializedName("students")
    @Expose
    private List<Student> students = null;

    public List<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
    }

    }
```

**APIInterface.java**

```
public interface APIService {
    @GET("/bins/tdze5")
    Observable<ResponseClass> getdata();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void getData() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Observable<ResponseClass> observable = apiService.getdata().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    observable.subscribe(new Observer<ResponseClass>() {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d("error",e.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(ResponseClass response) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Student> students = response.getStudents();
        Log.d("response size", String.valueOf(students.size()));
        for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++){
          Student student = new Student();
          student.setId(students.get(i).getId());
          student.setName(students.get(i).getName());
          list.add(student);
        }

        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyce = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyce);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Kabaia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66865355/i-am-facing-java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin plz help me